# What is the X(t) dependence of the ends of stretched Nambu-Goto string?

Tags: string-theory

I'd like to have an expression for the velocity of an end of an open string being contracted due to it's tension. Not that of transverse oscillations, which seems to be the velocity of light, but rather that of movement of an end in spacetime.

**Task**:  Initially I have an open Nambu-Goto string of length $\sigma_0$. I've stretched it from $\sigma_0$ to $\sigma_l$ and let to relax. Because it is strained with tension $T_0$ it wants to decrease ist length.

**Question**: What is the $X(t)$ dependence of string's endpoints (t-time, X-coordinates)? Could I regard the tension $T_0$ as a constant force acting on charges at the Ends of the string (Chan-Patton charges to my knowledge)? If it is so, I could describe the Motion of the strings Ends as a Motion of a relativistic particle: $X(t)=\frac{c^2}{F/m}(\sqrt{1+\frac{(t-t_0)F/m}{c}})^2-1)$? Or it it is not allowed?